# std::find_if gives "conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal" error

Tags: c++, std

I have the following function:

```
float Mesh::getTerrainHeight(Vector3f playerPos) {
    auto testIterator = std::find_if(meshVerticesFloats.begin(), meshVerticesFloats.end(), [&](Vector3f pos)
    {
        //check the X axis
        if (abs(playerPos.GetX() - pos.GetX()) < playerScale + vertexScale / 1.0f) {
            //check the Z axis
            if (abs(playerPos.GetZ() - pos.GetZ()) < playerScale + vertexScale / 1.0f) {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    if (testIterator != meshVerticesFloats.end()) {
        int testIndex = std::distance(meshVerticesFloats.begin(), testIterator);
        return meshVerticesFloats[testIndex].GetY();
    }
    else {
        return 10000.0f;//test value - no mesh vertex y value is ever 10000
    }
}
```

When I run I get the following error message:

```
2>c:\visual_studio_2017\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(174): error C2451: conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal
```

Is there something wrong with my `std::find_if` logic?

Answer (score 4):

The predicate should return something that can be converted to `bool`. More precisely ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)):

> p - unary predicate which returns ​true for the required element.
>
> **The expression p(v) must be convertible to bool** for every argument v of type (possibly const) VT, where VT is the value type of InputIt, regardless of value category, and must not modify v. Thus, a parameter type of VT&is not allowed, nor is VT unless for VT a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11). ​

Yours returns nothing:

```
return;
```

You probably wanted this instead:

```
 if (abs(playerPos.GetX() - pos.GetX()) < playerScale + vertexScale / 1.0f) {
     //check the Z axis
     if (abs(playerPos.GetZ() - pos.GetZ()) < playerScale + vertexScale / 1.0f) {
         return true;
     }
 }
 return false;
```

I don't know if this will give the correct result, thats up to you, but it "fixes" the error.

**PS** I suppose `Vector3f` is not your type, hence you should pass a `const Vector3f&` to the predicate, because `std::find_if` requires that a move should be equivalent to a copy when you use `Vector3f` as parameter for the predicate (see above).